# Error while running rails 2.0.0. "de" is not a valid locale (I18n::InvalidLocale)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ho together,

I had some problems with utf8 and ascii, in case of this I tried to update from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.0.0

that worked but now when I want to start my app I got this error:

```
/home/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!': :"de-DE" is not a valid locale (I18n::InvalidLocale)
    from /home/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:34:in `default_locale='
    from /home/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:35:in `default_locale='
    from /var/www/xyz/xyz/config/application.rb:79:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've set the

```
default_locale: de
```

in the settings.yml

Whats going wrong? and how can I fix it? I'm running under debian 7 and rails 3.2.12

Comment: maybe trying `de_DE` will help?

Comment: I've tried it, but same error: `enforce_available_locales!': :de_DE is not a valid locale (I18n::InvalidLocale)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try:

```
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false
config.i18n.available_locales = ["de_DE", :en]
config.i18n.default_locale = :'de_DE'
```

And let me know if that helps?

Comment: should i add this in application.rb?

Comment: okay application starts ... but not with ruby 2.0.0

if i run `rails s` it starts with 2.0.0 but then I'haven't access rights 

if i run `sudo rails s` it starts with 1.9.3 ....

Comment: Yes, in `config/application.rb`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a linux expert :-( and this seems like a whole other issue.

Comment: okay thanks, then I'll open a new question for this, but the first problem is solved :) thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the version to -> gem 'i18n', '0.6.0' on the gemfile and then run 'bundle update i18n'